# Can a probability be a random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I have some confusion over random variables and the law of total probability. Suppose I have a random variable $X$ that follows a pmf $f(x)=P(X=x)$. And suppose that this variable $X$ were to represent the proportion of white balls in an urn. This scenario is in a sense when one is drawing from an urn but is  unsure of the proportion of balls in the urn so they have a prior belief given by $f(x)$

Let $P(white)$ be the probability of drawing a white ball from the urn.
$$P(white)=\sum_{\forall x} P(white|X=x)P(X=x)=\sum_{\forall x} x P(X=x)=E(X)$$
(using the law of total probability)

But by definition the probability of drawing a white ball was $X$, which is a random variable, so wouldn't $P(white)$ also be a random variable? $E(X)$ is clearly just a non-stochastic constant so is it true that $P(white)=X$ or is there something wrong in using the law of total probability here?

Comment: One way to think of this: Each value of $x$ represents a different urn, with a different proportion of white balls.  Then $P(white)$ is the overall probability of getting a white ball if you put your hand into a random urn, where some urns may be more likely than others (according to the distribution of $X$.)  So $P(white)$ is a constant, not a random variable.

Comment: Then if you fix an urn, but you don't know what urn it is, and start drawing balls, the chance that you are drawing from a given urn changes: $P(X=x | \text{observed draws})$ can be computed by Bayes' theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The law of total probability is fine. Your mistake comes from (confusingly) assuming that $P(\textrm{white})$ is a random variable, in particular that it is $X$. In fact, it is not: it is a probability, which is just a constant, so can be equal to $E(X)$, which it is. That also makes sense: the chance of a white ball is the mean of all proportions, which is "intuitive" to me at least. $X$ is just a randomly drawn "proportion" so we can assume from what you have told us that $X$ is a $U(0,1)$ uniform random variable (this by the way makes your sum notation wrong: you need an integral if $X$ has support $\mathbb{R}$). Your sum notation is correct if $X$ has countable support.

Comment: So how do I express the fact that $P(white)$ is a random variable in itself (if that is even possible?). Something like $P(P(white)=x)=f(x)$. Would this be contradictory to the fact that $P(white)=E(X)$ ie just a constant?

Comment: @Lorenzo $P(\textrm{white})$ is actually not a random variable, also as jair-taylor pointed out, and as I did. The $white$ part is just an event: we drew white ball. The $P$ part is the probability measure. You could introduce another random variable $Y$ which has two values $white$ and $non-white$ and you can rewrite things as $P(Y = white) = ... $ if you wish, but $P(white)$ is a probability, not a random variable.